# what is the function in SQL (Sanbox) to change a string that's a reflected as a SKEW # to a name that. Ex. product_name says SKUu77 not bookcase

Tags: google-bigquery, where-clause, data-cleaning

Product_info lists all products sold ( fans, couches, bookcase, beds)
The text string in rows 28 & 29 say (SKU77417, SKU13351) but need **row 28 to say bed** and **row 29 to say bookcase** instead.

This is the query I wrote to pull-null values in a list, then I added a WHERE clause to change the SKU to the correct names but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT 
  Coalesce(product, product_code) As product_info
FROM 
  `myfirst-bigquery-project001.Customer_Data.Customer_purchase`
WHERE 
 SKU77417 = 'bed' AND SKU13351 = 'bookcase'
```

I was expecting this to replace the SKU to the names I needed, can anyone show me the correct way to write the query to properly change the sku to those names?

Comment: It's weird that you spell **Stock Keeping Unit** as SKEW because the word Unit does not start with either an E or a W.

Answer (score 0):

Please always provide a table with some sample data in your question. The names of the columns are not clear. Please fix the names in this wiki answer!

```
SELECT 
  case when product_code = 'SKU77417' then 'bed'
when product_code = 'SKU77417' then 'bookcase'
else product_name 
end
FROM 
  `myfirst-bigquery-project001.Customer_Data.Customer_purchase`
WHERE 
product_code = 'SKU77417' or product_code= 'SKU13351'
 SKU77417 = 'bed' AND SKU13351 = 'bookcase'
```

Do you want to change a existing table?

```
UPDATE  `myfirst-bigquery-project001.Customer_Data.Customer_purchase`
SET product_name = 'bed'
WHERE product_name = 'SKU77417';
```